# Matching two ID columns and return the most recent entry from a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have 2 tables, both with a common ID column. The second table contains multiple rows matching the ID column in the first table, and I need to return the most recent entry from the second table. My solution below is almost correct, but it returns a single value across all ID columns, and not the value corresponding to that actual ID column.

As you can see, it is dealing with payments, so just need to return the date that the most recent payment covers.

```
(SELECT TOP 1CONVERT(VARCHAR,MemberPayments.CoverFinishDay,105)
FROM
    Members LEFT JOIN MemberPayments
        ON Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID
        AND MemberPayments.CoverFinishDay = (
            SELECT MAX(CoverFinishDay)
            FROM MemberPayments
            WHERE Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID
        ))
```

Any idea why it would just be returning one value across all?

Comment: you built a query selecting a single field with a `top 1` in the `select` clause. a single value is the correct and expected result and you can't expect anything else.

Comment: How would I select just the first value from the subquery?

Comment: your question makes no sense. you have `MAX` in the subquery; that means you will get a single value from that query so asking for the first value is useless... with a single value that single value will always be the first: it is the one and only value you can get!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
;WITH LatestMemPayments AS
(
    SELECT   MemberID
            ,CoverFinishDay = MAX(CoverFinishDay)
    FROM    MemberPayments
    GROUP BY MemberID
)

SELECT *
FROM Members            ME
JOIN LatestMemPayments  MP  ON ME.MemberID = MP.MemberID
```

Written as derived table instead of CTE;

```
SELECT *
FROM Members            ME
JOIN    (
            SELECT   MemberID
                    ,CoverFinishDay = MAX(CoverFinishDay)
            FROM    MemberPayments
            GROUP BY MemberID
        )               MP  ON ME.MemberID = MP.MemberID
```

Potentially as a single query;

```
SELECT   ME.Col1
        ,ME.Col2
        ,CoverFinishDay = MAX(MP.CoverFinishDay)
FROM Members        ME
JOIN MemberPayments MP  ON ME.MemberID = MP.MemberID
GROUP BY ME.Col1
        ,ME.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will find all information in MemberPayments for the latest data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  Members
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT top 1 * 
 FROM 
   MemberPayments 
 WHERE 
   Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID 
 ORDER BY 
   CoverFinishDay DESC) x
```

If you just need the latest date:

```
SELECT m.MemberID, m.Field2, m.Field3, max(mp.CoverFinishDay) as LatestDate
FROM 
  Members m
LEFT JOIN
   MemberPayments mp
ON
   Members.MemberID = MemberPayments.MemberID 
GROUP BY m.MemberID, m.Field2, m.Field3
```

Comment: Nope... Somehow I still get the same result; the same value for all ID's.

Comment: @user2878266 could you include some data ? This seems correct to me